# How to add options to a argument in slash command?

Tags: discord.py, nextcord

How do I add options to a slash command like:

[image: This.]

I'm not asking for a code, but I can't find out how to add options like these into a slash command.
Please answer this.

Comment: I'd recommend reading the documentation on Application Commands (https://docs.nextcord.dev/en/latest/interactions.html) and checking out the examples (https://github.com/nextcord/nextcord/tree/master/examples/application_commands)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use nextcord but its similiar for discord.py replace `nextcord` with `discord`

```
@nextcord.slash_command
async def command(self, interaction: Interaction, category: str = nextcord.SlashOption(name="", description="", choices=["option1", "option2"])):
    if category == "option1":
       await interaction.response.send_message("hello")
    elif category == "option2":
       await interaction.response.send_message("bye")
```

This slash command is inside a cog