# trying to make a choose command (like pls choose)

Tags: discord.py

I've been trying to code a choose command like how dank memer has one but without the slash commands but the problem is i dont have that much coding knowledge to make the bot choose beetween 2 things so i did a code like this:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def choose(ctx, *, message1, message2):
    possible_responses = [
        f"i choose {message1}",
        f"i choose {message2}",
    ]

await ctx.send(random.choice(possible_responses) + " ")
```

the code worked but it only send "i choose" so how can i make my bot choose beetween 2 words and send the answer?

Comment: Does this meet your requirements, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73183632/how-to-add-options-to-a-argument-in-slash-command/73184436#73184436

Comment: im not using slash commands though but i will look at it

Comment: they use nextcord and they have slash commands so no it doesnt

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple way of doing it,

```
@bot.command()
async def choose(ctx, option1, option2, option3):
    choices = [option1, option2, option3]
    await ctx.send(f"I choose, {random.choice(choices)}")
```

Comment: Note that you should definitely sanitize your input using `AllowedMentions`.